# Linux Log all tcp new connections

Tags: iptables, tcp, connection, conntrack

On my linux host I want to get per minute logs of all the new tcp connections being created. 
I have multiple tap devices on my host from which various are trying to create the tcp connections.

I have iptable POSTROUTING MASQUERADE rule on my host.
So my requirement is to log the tcp connections such that I got to know at particular time which tap device Ip/Port is mapped to particular port of host for that request.

One solution I got:

> sudo conntrack -E --event-mask NEW --output timestamp

But I looking for something which requires minimimum CPU/Memory and other resources.

BPF BCC https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/tree/b181a8e796bc42b53587e7e2f8008ab38a8fef8c has tcpconnect for that but it publishes only for eth0 not for other virtual network devices

Answer (score 0):

Most CPU friendly way to do it - use [the ipt netflow iptables target](https://github.com/aabc/ipt-netflow) with nat events activated. But it isn't simple and requires additional software (a netflow collector and a netflow analyzer).

Other way is usage of ULOGD2 daemon with built-in support of conntrack ([example of configuration](https://home.regit.org/2014/02/logging-connection-tracking-event-with-ulogd/)). It's very efficient too.